# Running the benchmark with a multicore simulator will only get the same data？

Tags: benchmarking, gem5

When using a CPU simulator such as sniper or gem5 to run a benchmark program such as SPEC2006 in conjunction with the MCPAT power consumption model, whether a benchmark program only gets one set of power data .

For example, if I run the FFT benchmark, I will only get the same set of power data no matter how many times I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use McPat after collecting the stats of my simulations and it gives me different power data based benchmark and number of instructions simulated. You could try writing a script to convert m5 stats file to xml and use McPat to calculate the average power.

Comment: I mean, for example, when I run the FFT benchmark for splash2 using a gem5 simulator and get the output data, I use MCPAT to calculate the average power based on that. In such a flow, if the FFT benchmark is run multiple times, you will get the same set of power data, or will you get multiple sets of power data with slightly different sets of power data

Comment: Because it’s an average power, no matter how many instructions you run. Example: if a benchmark has 1k executable instructions, running it for 2M instructions will get the same average power/energy.

Comment: If you are attaching a hardware accelerator or you have you own hardware attached, you can run simulations with and without you hardware then use McPat to calculate energy/power then get the difference in average power. The difference is what your extra hardware has consumed.

Comment: My experiment was conducted entirely in the Linux virtual machine of Ubuntu, so MCPAT calculates the average power of gem5 running the FFT benchmark process, so can the instantaneous power be calculated, and if the instantaneous power is calculated, can multiple sets of power data be obtained?

Comment: What you mean by instantaneous power. You should read some AMD slides that talks about calculating power consumption without using any other tools like mcpat. No body is going to reveal their code for you. Good luck doing it with Power modules provided by gem5 then. This  will take you years to do it. Fui, ad uses gem5 as a secondary tool to estimate total power consumption.

Comment: So normally a benchmark program only produces a set of power files, right?Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You are still far from doing gem5. Good luck with your journey.

Comment: Please teach me how to run VM in gem5.. hahahahha

Comment: Haha, actually, I've only touched gem5, so to use it as an example, I'm really using the sniper multi-core simulator now.

Comment: Then why are you asking questions for gem5. This is weird!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Because their logic is similar, and there are too few people who use sniper。hah